# Creating sets of geom_points from class list

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a class list (L) made up of 20 data frames (with names below) that look like this (I can't make a reasonably clear table or embed the image, so here's a link to the image):

[[image: data frame]

the data frames have the follow names:

```
"FGN" "FGS" "FGM" "FGT" "FGL" "CN"  "CS"  "CM"  "CT"  "CL"  "SN"  "SS"  "SM"  "ST"  "SL"  "ON"  "OS"  "OM" "OT"  "OL"
```

Which correspond to the headers in the data frame (all the data frames came from a bigger table that was broken down to give frames with all 1s in each column).

Essentially I want to plot all of the coordinates for each of the data frames onto a map, with different colours for each prefix (FGx, Cx, Sx, Ox) and different alphas for each suffix (xN, xS, xM, xT, xL).

For the colors I've done this:

```
col <- floor(seq(by=0.2, length.out=length(n)))
col <- data.frame(col)
rownames(col) <- n
```

with n being the names above.

I envisaged something similar for the alpha values, but I'm not sure how to implement that. Simply creating a sequence like above, and then taking away all the unit values from it. There's probably a better way.

Then with this, I want to create geom_points with ggplot.

So for each of the data.frames in the class list something like this (though this for some reason doesn't work):

```
FGNGeo <- geom_point(data=L$FGN,aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, col=col["FGN","col"],alpha=alpha["FGN","alpha"]))
```

But this for all the names, without having to type it all out.

I don't know how to do this last part, and would really appreciate some help with it. I'm constantly looking through tutorials, but this stuff is complicated(!) so don't be too hard on me. 
\

EDIT:

```
dput(head(activities,15))

structure(list(Latitude = c(51.481435, 51.478936, 51.481655, 
51.456898, 51.476709, 51.48305, 51.487558, 51.485591, 51.485591, 
51.483357, 51.488441, 51.488441, 51.473205, 51.480465, 51.484981
), Longitude = c(-0.31310288, -0.32133158, -0.31403087, -0.36147879, 
-0.34428084, -0.31033569, -0.30246309, -0.30884466, -0.30884466, 
-0.30356965, -0.3013212, -0.3013212, -0.33304685, -0.30318732, 
-0.31268398), FGN = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), FGS = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), FGM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), FGT = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), FGL = c(0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), CN = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), CS = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CM = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), CT = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CL = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), SN = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), SS = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), SM = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ST = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), SL = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), ON = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), OS = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), OM = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), OT = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), OL = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Latitude", 
"Longitude", "FGN", "FGS", "FGM", "FGT", "FGL", "CN", "CS", "CM", 
"CT", "CL", "SN", "SS", "SM", "ST", "SL", "ON", "OS", "OM", "OT", 
"OL"), row.names = c(13L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 
26L, 28L, 33L, 34L, 36L, 45L, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do you want one plot per dataframe, or do you need to combine them first?

Comment: One plot per dataframe, I need to play around with how to combine them later. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(yourdata)` or `dput(head(yourdata,15))` if it's large?

Comment: I've added it to the original post.

Comment: Thanks. Do all values need to be plotted, or only the 1's?

Comment: In each data set within L, all coordinates need to be plotted with colour and alpha dependent on the name of the data set. Thanks

Comment: I meant that in your data, you have columns of 1's and 0's. Do you need a point for each combiantion of lat long for each dataset, or only if there's a 1 in a certain column?

Comment: I've added both options to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start for you. Generally in ggplot, you need to have all data for each point that you want to plot on one line in the data. In other words, your data needs to be in 'long' format, with columns for pre and suffix. Then the awesome functionalities of ggplot2 make it very easy to create alpha- and color-scales.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

#turn to long
dat_long <- melt(activities,id.var=c("Longitude","Latitude"))

#identify pre- and suffixes. Can probably cleaner, but you get the idea
#prefix: remove last character
dat_long$prefix <- sub("[A-Z]$","",dat_long$variable)
#suffix: get last character
dat_long$suffix <- substring(dat_long$variable, nchar(as.character(dat_long$variable)))

p1 <- ggplot(dat_long, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, alpha=suffix, color=prefix)) +   
geom_point(size=3)
```

added facet grid to show actual scales, lots over overplotting...

[image]

If only plotting the points with '1' in the data:

```
p2 <- ggplot(dat_long[dat_long$value==1,], aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, alpha=suffix, color=prefix)) + 
  geom_point(size=3)
```

[image]

Comment: The second option is what I was trying to explain, thanks. I'm trying to plot this over a map, I've done: map = get_map(location = c(lon = -0.3131029, lat = 51.48143), zoom = 12, maptype = 'roadmap') but when I try to add the plot to it, I get the error: Error in p + o : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("+.gg", "Ops.data.frame") for "+"

Comment: I think you need to add the geom point only, with the data and aes arguments from my code.